# Implementing Doubly Linked List from scratch, error in remove() method

Tags: java, data-structures

I was trying to learn to implement Doubly Linked List in java just as an exercise.
but I am stuck at `remove()` method.

The contents of the list are,

```
1 2 3 4
```

When I try to remove the element which is not present.It shows the `NullPointerException` at `line no. 21` instead of printing `not found`.

The other codes that I saw was a little complicated and different from what I am doing. 
The method is,

```
 void remove(int data){
    Node n = head;
    if(head==null)
        System.out.println("Not Found");
    else if(head.d==data){
        if(head==tail){
            head=null;
            tail=null;
        }
        else{
            head=head.next;
            head.prev=null;
        }
    }
    else{
        while(n!=null && n.d==data){
            n=n.next;
        }
        if(n==tail){
            tail=tail.prev;
            tail.next=null;
        }
        else if(n!=null){
            n.prev.next=n.next;
            n.next.prev=n.prev;
        }
        if(n==null)
            System.out.println("Not Found");
    }
}
```

So my Question is,
Am I doing it completely wrong?
OR what is the problem?
Pardon me if it's just too foolish.

Comment: Does it give the `NullPointerException` for *every* input or just for some inputs? What is the content of the list and what is the input when it gives you the exception?

Comment: Can you please post exact stacktrace to help us reach to conclusion bit faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with search logic. In the while loop condition "n.d == data" is incorrect. It should be "n.d != data" i.e.

while(n!=null && n.d==data){
            n=n.next;
        }

**Should be:**

```
...

    while(n!=null && n.d != data){
        n=n.next;
    }
```

Here is a much cleaner implementation :

```
public void remove(int data) { // Head is not required in param, should be field variable
    Node ptr = head;

    while(ptr!=null && ptr.data != data) // search for the node
    {
        ptr = ptr.next;
    }

    if(ptr == null) {
        System.out.println("Not Found");
        return;
    }

    if(ptr.prev == null) {// match found with first node
        head = ptr.next;
    }
    else{
        ptr.prev.next = ptr.next;
    }
    if(ptr.next == null){// match found with last node
        tail = ptr.prev;
    }
    else{
        ptr.next.prev = ptr.prev;
    }       
}
```

Comment: If the Node to be remove is last then it will be the **tail** node and `if` block above `else if` mentioned in the answer I think does that. I am not sure if I am stating it correct or  I am just misunderstanding your statements.

Comment: Probably my bad. Modified the answer. Check if it helps. BTW, you modified the question i guess. Earlier there was a parameter  'Node head' (which you should not do otherwise you can not change the head reference) (Y)

Comment: won't the method you suggested, cause unnecessary loop cycles

Answer (score 0):

```
void remove(Node head, int value) {
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("Not Found");
    } else if (value == head.d) {
        if (head == tail) {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        } else {
            head = head.next;
            head.prev = null;
        }
    } else {
        Node n = head.next;
        while (n != null && value != n.d) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        if (n == tail) {
            tail.next = null;
            tail = tail.prev;
        } else if (n != null) {
            n.prev.next = n.next;
            n.next.prev = n.prev;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am enable to figure out, What has happened? By just interchanging `line no. 21` and `line no. 22`. And even after not showing `NullPointerException`. It does not tell when the element is not present, Unless the list is empty.